# How to get MinValue/MaxValue of a certain ValueType via reflection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I need to this at runtime. I checked using Reflector and value types line like Int16, for example, should contain

```
<Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), ComVisible(True)> _
Public Structure Int16
    Implements IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable(Of Short), IEquatable(Of Short)

Public Const MaxValue As Short = &H7FFF
Public Const MinValue As Short = -32768


End Structure
```

But the following code is not working

```
Dim dummyValue = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(UInt16))
Dim minValue As IComparable =    DirectCast(dummyValue.GetType.GetProperty("MinValue").GetValue(dummyValue,
Nothing), IComparable)
```

any idea how to solve?

**EDIT**: only for the example I used directly **GetType(UInt16)** but in real code this part is substituted by an instance of unknown-at-design-time .NET Type

Comment: If the type is unknown at design time how can you be sure that it will always have the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` fields?

Comment: I know that this type is a ValueType but not which specific type it is

Comment: But there's no guarantee that subclasses of `ValueType` will have `MinValue` or `MaxValue` fields.

Comment: That's true, using ValueType was wrong :D in short I am sure that this type is Byte, SByte, UShort, Short, UInt or Int. These types for sure have MinValue and MaxValue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `GetType.GetField("MinValue")`.
Constants are considered Fields

Comment: We're all noobs (Skeet excluded), make yourself comfortable.

Comment: @eschneider your are right! this is also one of the reason why I like this place, I can go and take a coffee and when I come back most of times I find an helpful answer

Comment: For newer types like Half, Int128, UInt18 Min and MaxValue have become properties. So you need to know that sometimes its a (const) field and sometimes a property.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hanin who answered long before me. Here's some example code with his answer.

In this example an integer value (of 17) is assigned to an object variable. Then the static field MinValue of this type is retrieved and, if it exists, the value of this field is assigned to the object variable:

```
FieldInfo fi;
object objInt = 17;

if((fi = objInt.GetType().GetField("MinValue")) != null)
{
   objInt = fi.GetValue(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Property it's a constant...

Any reason you can't just call?:
         Integer.MaxValue
        Integer.MinValue

Comment: I added more details why I cannot use it